# fixed div and see the lower height data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one button, when I click in this button one `div` generates in the body which has this css:

```
div#transparentDiv {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  opacity: 0.7;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0 !important;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 95;
}
```

and one `div` that has none css display, remove none display and get this css

```
.popUp {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 37px;
  z-index: 98;
  width: 61%;
  background-color: #d8d8d8;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

now my problem is this section, my `div` that fixed and i can't see full content,
and when I scroll page this `div` fixed and don't scroll down to see the lower height

What should I do?

Comment: You need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Without any HTML this is realy hard to answer. Try to add

```
overflow: scroll;
```

or

```
overflow: auto;
```

To your fixed div. Then you can scroll the content of your div seperatly.

Answer (score 0):

If you could scroll down to see the contents of a fixed div, then it would not be fixed would it?

try this:

```
.popUp {
  position: absolute;
}
```